# How to make automated server-side API calls every 15 minites without client request in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make NextJs app that every 15 minutes makes API calls on the server and saves results in database.
And then clients would fetch data from my database and not from the 3rd party API provider.
The purpose of such setup is to avoid overrunning daily API calls limit given by the 3rd party provider.

I cannot get the idea where in my app should I put the function that fetches data from API on server start and does so every 15 minutes.

Any idea?

Comment: After the server starts, run setInterval or its equivalent to poll the API and record the result

Comment: Why would you need your app to do this? Just use cron to run `node runthisthing.js` every 15 minutes, with runthisthing.js being a stand-alone .js file that queries your API and writes to the database.

Comment: Never used cron. I'll give it a try. Thanks for suggestion